ios push notification not received after getting out of airplane mode
I'm sending a push notification using Noticed Gem during the night when my phone is in airplane mode. When I wake up and disable the airplane mode, I don't get the push notification.
These are the settings:
  def ios_format(apn)
      apn.custom_payload = { universal_link: url }
      apn.alert = { title: title(recipient), body: message(recipient) }
      apn.sound = 'default'
      apn.priority = '10' # Send immediately, bypassing the
  end

default expiration is supposed to be 30 days.
How can I debug/fix the problem? (with noticed gem)
I checked Apple consoleKIT, and I don't see discarded notifications.
Thanks

Monitor delivery metrics using the Push Notifications Console

Just to make sure: It works if your device is not in airplane mode when you send the noditification? But actually, once the notification has been accepted by the APNS backend, delivery is pretty much out of your hand ...

@derpirscher correct, works if device is not in airplane mode.

Did you try setting an explicit expiry? By any chance do you set a default of 0 for you expiry somewhere? Because that would mean "discard if it cannot be delivered immediately"?

Yes I set an explicit expiry of 2 days, still does not work..

Seems to be a possible solution from apple developer forum:
The reason you are not getting a notification when the device comes back online is, by that time, the notification you sent to it is lost. This is due to your push server seemingly having multiple push tokens for the same device.
Let me explain: APNs stores undelivered notifications until they expire -OR- until another notification is sent to the same device for the same app. In your case you have sent a number of notifications to some other tokens, which happen to be older unused tokens (probably belonging to the older versions of the app) which are destined for the same device.
The problem arises, because APNs stores the subsequent notifications overwriting the one you sent at 4:09, the 4:09 notification is lost. When the device comes back online, APNs tries to send the last notification over, but because you have used a token that is no longer valid, that notification which gets sent is never received.
While you may get an error (410) from APNs when using tokens no longer in use, if and when a token will start triggering this error is is randomized to protect the user's privacy. In the meantime, you will want to clean up your token database to ensure there aren't multiple tokens per device or user. Under some circumstances, for example if you delete and app and install a new version, you will get assigned a new token. You would want to make sure that the existing token for that device is removed from your list of tokens.


Verify that your APNs certificates or tokens are properly configured on both the server-side and in the iOS project.

The priority that you have set (10) is meant to deliver notifications right away. However, keep in mind that high-priority notifications might be delivered immediately and discarded if the device is unreachable (in your case airplane mode). Try testing with lower priority (for example 5).

You mentioned that there are no discarded notifications in ConsoleKit, but it's a good idea to also check the device logs directly from the device using Xcode. Connect your device, open Xcode, go to Window -> Devices and Simulators, select your device, and view the logs and look for any errors related to push notifications.

Add additional logs wherever possible. Log the response received from APNs on server-side when the push notification is sent. APNs provides a response indicating the success or failure of each notification request.



(1) is obviously the case, because OP says it works, when the device is online.  (2) Do you have any source for that claim? It seems rather counter-intuitive, that a high priority message would be discarded if the device isn't immediately reachable

Storing and forwarding iOS push notifications
After iOS Airplane Mode deactivation, only the last push notification will be received. This is the typical behavior of the Cupertino's APNs push API. It's absolutely independent of Ruby on Rails Noticed gem or similar services. So, if multiple notifications are sent while the iOS device is offline, each new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. Also, that last notification is stored for a limited period of time (I didn't find the exact number in the official documentation). If user's device remains offline for a long period of time, any notifications that were being stored for it are discarded.
Recommendation
Try adding a non-zero expiration, id and authorization header fields. It would also be a great idea to duplicate a notification via email.
For details, read Sending notification requests to APNs and Communicating with APNs articles.

I have tried adding expiration and it still does not work

"After iOS Airplane Mode deactivation, only the last push notification will be received. This is the typical behavior of the Cupertino's APNs push API." Is there any source for that claim?  And even if that was the case, then still at leas one notification should pop up after deactivating flight mode ...

And for your idea of duplicating push notifications via email: I strongly disagree with you about that. First of all, the backend may not even know the users email address. And second, if everything works as expected, why would I want to receive each notification twice (except for really important things like failed payments or similar)? Once via push and once via email. I'd be pretty annoyed if an app did this.
